# Local Lock Object Variable in Function

Tags: c#

While attempting to interpret someone else's code, I stumbled onto this method of locking, and I am perplexed:

```
public void CloseHandle(SafeFileHandle handle)
{
   var thisLock = new Object();

   lock (thisLock)
       handle.Close();
}
```

To me, this appears to be locking on a new instance of an object every time the method is called, thereby never actually "locking" at all since more than one thread will never lock on the same instance of the object. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: The lock block by itself will put up a memory barrier, that’s it. The actual (internal) monitor calls won’t have any effect to prevent concurrent execution of that block of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, that's a bug and no real locking is happening